# rvm list known differs between develop and production

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

I was planing to upgrade my ruby version for a project. On 1.9.3 so was thinking it was good idea to do in steps. First step would be 2.0.0, I run `rvm list known` and get this

```
...
[ruby-]1.9.3[-p551]
[ruby-]2.0.0[-p648]
[ruby-]2.1[.1 
...
```

But when I run the same command on my production server I get

```
[ruby-]1.9.2[-p330]
[ruby-]1.9.3[-p547]
[ruby-]2.0.0-p481
[ruby-]2.0.0[-p576]
[ruby-]2.1.2
```

Why do these list differs ? Seems like it would be a good idea to use the same version on both dev and prod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each RVM version has a hardcoded list of known Ruby versions. If the list differs between installtions, it is generally caused by different RVM versions.

Try to upgrade your RVM version to get the most up-to-date list. With current RVM versions, you can update RVM by running

```
rvm get latest
```